# Is it good practice to set default value in constructor to undefined?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a code which looks like this:

```
constructor(data) {
    this.date = data.date && new Date(data.date) || undefined
}
```

Is it good practice/needed to add `|| undefined`. If `date.date` will be empty this expression will return null. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

> If date.date will be empty this expression will return null. Am I right?

No.

If `data.date` is a falsy value, it will assign `data.date`. That might be `0` or `null` or `""` or `false` or …

Explicitly setting it to `undefined` will at least make it consistent which could be important for later code which tests the value.